# Loading AD groups is resulting a MSGraphAPI Error - Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. SPFX - Ms Graph

Tags: graph, spfx, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to load my groups from ad but it keeps giving me an error. I have shipped and also added it to my site app.
I have also followed a couple of tutorial but to no avail.
Any help or input on whether or not I am doing something wrong would be appreciated.

A part of my package-solution.json

```
    "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "Group.Read.All"
      }
    ],
```

Employee.tsx

```
export interface IEmployeeListProps {
  description: string;
  context: WebPartContext;
}

const EmployeeList = (props: IEmployeeListProps) => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<IUserItem[]>([]);
  const [usersToShow, setUsersToShow] = useState([]);

  function searchFunction(filter: string) {
    if (filter == "") {
      return setUsers(usersToShow);
    } if (filter != "") {
      let qf = users.filter((v) => v.displayName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filter.toLocaleLowerCase()));
      setUsers(qf);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient("3")
      .then((client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
        client
          .api("/groups")
          .version("v1.0")
          .select("")
          .get((err: any, res: any) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error("MSGraphAPI Error")
              console.error(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log(res);
            setUsers(res.value);
            setUsersToShow(res.value);
          }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
      }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) })
  }, []);



  return (
    <div onLoad={() => console.log("Page has been loaded")} style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <input onChange={(e) => searchFunction(e.target.value)} type="text" style={{ margin: "9px" }} />
      {users.map((v) => {
        return (
          <div style={{ padding: "5px", fontSize: "19px", fontWeight: "bolder", fontFamily: "sans-serif" }}>
            {v.displayName}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmployeeList
```

Comment: Have you consented the permissions on the SharePoint admin center under api permissions? The code looks "fine". Well..you are trying to get groups but your variable name is users ;)

Comment: Yeah, the project was to unitially load the users but a change of plans resulted the groups needing to be loaded instead. I figured as much that it was something to do with the permissions on sharepoint. Shipping the project and adding it to the website fixed the issue : ).